# Get a type in python with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm working in a simple script to load a dump file into an AWS RDS Oracle install.

But I have some problems getting the FILE_TYPE with connection.gettype

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import cx_Oracle
size_limit=1024
print(cx_Oracle.clientversion())

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("XXX", "XX", "XXXX:XXX/XXX")
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    typeObj = connection.gettype("VARCHAR")
    OTYPE = connection.gettype("UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE")
    NFILE = cursor.callfunc('UTL_FILE.FOPEN',returnType=OTYPE,parameters=['DATA_PUMP_DIR','BIOMGRDB_DEV-test.dmp','wb',size_limit]) 

    f = open("BIOMGRDB_DEV.dmp", "rb")
    try:
        byte = f.read(size_limit)
        while byte != "":
            # Do stuff with byte.
            print("Reading")
            print(byte)
            cursor.callfunc('UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW', parameters=[NFILE,byte])
            byte = f.read(size_limit)
    finally:
        cursor.callfunc('UTL_FILE.FCLOSE', parameters=[NFILE])
        f.close()
finally:
    print("FINALLY")
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Error is as following, no matter what type I use:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: OCI-22303: type ""."UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE" not found
```

It looks like it is trying to find the type inner a package.

I ran the following PL/SQL code just to ensure I have privileges to write files:

```
declare 
  fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DATA_PUMP_DIR', 'test_file', 'w');

  UTL_FILE.PUT(fHandle, 'This is the first line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT(fHandle, 'This is the second line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the third line');

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
end;
```

And it works well.

Here my enviornmet configuration:

Python           2.7.13
Instant client   (19, 3, 0, 0, 0)
cx_Oracle        7.1.3
Oracle               12c

I hope someone can help me.

---

Update

I create a new type as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE1 AS OBJECT 
( SOMETHING VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

And if i use it as following:

```
OTYPE = connection.gettype("TYPE1")
```

It works and I get the following error:

```
NFILE = cursor.callfunc('UTL_FILE.FOPEN',returnType=OTYPE,parameters=['DATA_PUMP_DIR','BIOMGRDB_DEV-test.dmp','wb',size_limit])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

Now, I have a question: How can I use the FILE_TYPE object in cx_Oracle?

I also tried to create a synonym and it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: If all else fails with the PL/SQL permission issue, wrap the call to UTL_FILE.FOPEN in a PL/SQL block that binds the 3 scalar types of the returned FILE_TYPE

Comment: I tried it but It does not work as I was specting. So, I made it with perl using annonymous blocks. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you can do it in perl, you can do it in cx_Oracle

Comment: Maybe, but it works and it is fine for me. It was not needed in any particular language. I only need to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

This works exactly as expected:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@host/service")
fileType = conn.gettype("UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sizeLimit = 1024
result = cursor.callfunc("UTL_FILE.FOPEN", fileType,
        ["DATA_PUMP_DIR", "test_file", "wb", sizeLimit])
print("Result:", result)
```

Please try that script and advise the error and traceback you get. Also please advise on the exact version of the database you are using. There are limitations for using PL/SQL types like records (which is what UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE is).

Comment: I tried that, I got the same error. In fact, if you check my code I have that sniped.

Comment: Print out the results of ``conn.version``

Comment: Result is: 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: There may be limitations with that version. I don't have a 12.1 database available to confirm. If you are able to try with a newer database (use XE if you want a simple standalone database) that would be helpful.